# Text blend mode in div with transparent background

Tags: css

Is it possible to add mix-blend-mode to text in a div with background colour transparent?

I have a fixed bar on top with background transparent so I can scroll and let everything visible. But now I want to add blend mode: Exlusion to my text inside nabber. Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the RGBa format for the background color this should work.

Test like this:

```
background-color: rgba(10,23,55,0.5);
```

Where 0.5 is the opacity level.

For older browsers (IE9-) the solution is another. Then you can use 2 divs, not descendants of each other, and place them on top of each other.

Alternative is to use semi-transparent .png as background image using background-repeat in case div size is adaptive.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I put transparency in the background colour, the mix-blend-mode stops working.